# Send email with php when value changes

Tags: php, email

I would like to send an email with Php, to notify a change of status. Here is the code.

```
public function statut( $id ) {

    $info = get_post_meta( $id, '_ecole_statut', true );

    $statut = array(
        'transport'         => 'Transport normal',
        'transport_cl'      => 'success',
        'ecole'                 => 'École ouverte',
        'ecole_cl'          => 'success',
        'commentaire'   => ''
    );

    if( $info && current_time( 'timestamp' ) <= $info['date'] ){
        switch ($info['transport']){
            case "non":
                $statut['transport'] = "Transport annulé";
                $statut['transport_cl'] = 'danger';
            break;
            case "autre":
                $statut['transport'] = "Transport perturbé";
                $statut['transport_cl'] = 'warning';
            break;
            default:
                $statut['transport']  = "Transport normal";
                $statut['transport_cl'] = 'success';
            break;
        }
        switch ($info['ecole']){
            case "non":
                $statut['ecole'] = "École fermée";
                $statut['ecole_cl'] = 'danger';
            break;
            default:
                $statut['ecole'] = "École ouverte";
                $statut['ecole_cl'] = 'success';
            break;
        }

        $statut['commentaire'] = !empty( $info['commentaire'] ) ? '<small>' . $info['commentaire'] . '</small>' : '';
    }

    return $statut;
}
```

And here is the line that I tried, but it's sending email, for all the list of school instead of sending just for the one who change and I end un with 10 emails in my inbox. I would like it to display the name of the school and the status of the schools with "Transport annulé" "Transport perturbé" and "École fermée"

```
if ($tatut ['transport'] = "Transport annulé")
{
    mail('aport-lis@cscmonavenir.ca',
         'Nouvelle alerte intemperies',
          "".$abbr." Transport " .$statut['transport'] .
          " Ecole ".$statut['ecole']."");
}
```

Comment: What does `$tatut` contain? Why do you run a check within a `if` using only a single `=`?

Answer (score 0):

`if ($tatut ['transport'] = "Transport annulé")` needs to read `if ($tatut ['transport'] == "Transport annulé")`

You are setting the value to "Transport annulé" in your if statement when you use single `=`, you need to use double `==` to compare.

Answer (score 0):

This line looks problematic

```
if ($tatut ['transport'] = "Transport annulé")
```

First, it looks like a typo and instead of `$tatut` you want `$statut`. But aside from that, comparision uses `==` (or `===`). Using single `=` means assignment and your condition is always `true`.

Comment: Thank you for the typo, I corrected it. When I use == or === nothing happen, I don't get any email

Comment: Actually it did I received 200 emails again